# cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')

Tags: c++, cin

What does `cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')` mean in C++?

Does it actually ignore the last input from the user?

Comment: can explain a little bit more detail? thanks

Comment: A [reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/ignore) is an easy way to find out what things do.

Comment: hacker rank uses this for `int main` when you select c++ as your language

Answer (score 48, accepted):

This line ignores the rest of the current line, up to `'\n'` or `EOF` - whichever comes first:

- `'\n'` sets the delimiter, i.e. the character after which `cin` stops ignoring
- `numeric_limits<streamsize>::max()` sets the maximum number of characters to ignore. Since this is the upper limit on the size of a stream, you are effectively telling `cin` that there is no limit to the number of characters to ignore.

Comment: So the max() determine how many characters to ignore from the cin input, is that right? In my case, it's everything since it is max? @dasblinkenlight

Comment: @Zyi Yes, the first parameter determines how many characters to ignore. In your case that's `max()`, meaning "ignore as much as is needed."

Comment: as there might be something like this:
typedef _Longlong streamsize;
it have to assume that max() will return a value of maybe LONGLONG_MAX - this is a finite number. no reason to assume "there is no limit". the limit is thus a finite value but at the same time a rather big value.

Comment: it extracts and discards the rest of the current line, why are so many answers saying it "ignores"

Comment: @csguy Because "extract and discard" is a low-level description of what it means for a program to "ignore" characters.

Answer (score 0):

> cin.ignore(numeric_limits < streamsize > ::max(), '\n');

Here, the `\n` acts as a delimiter.... that is the point upto which the code has to be ignored(as "\n" in this perticular case). 
And `max()` defines that there is no limit for how much can be ignored, the spaces, tabs have to be ignored untill the line ends.

Answer (score 0):

This code says that the input has to be ignored on 2 basis
-1 if '\n' is read
-2 if limit is reached

as limit is max therefore only '\n' is the main condition to be considered