# is there is a way to add a number of lines the user enter using c++?

Tags: c++

I have tried to make it using dynamic string array but when I tried to add 2 lines it only adds one I don't know why 
 here is my code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int x;
    string name;
    string* lines;
    cout << "Input the file name to be opened : ";
    cin >> name;
    cout << endl << "Input the number of lines to be written : ";
    cin >> x;
    lines = new string[x];
    cout << endl << "The lines are :";
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        getline(cin,lines[i]);
    }
    fstream File(name, ios::out | ios::app);
    for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        File << lines[i] << endl;
    }
    File.close();
}
```

and it gives me this warning: 
C6385   Reading invalid data from 'lines':  the readable size is '(unsigned int)*28+4' bytes, but '56' bytes may be read

Comment: Save yourself headaches and use `std::vector<std::string>`.  It will relieve you of issues like you are having.

Comment: Alternatively, just append each line to the file (in the input loop) as you read it.  There is no apparent need for this program to store all the lines in memory.

Comment: Note also that after `cin >> x`, any extra whitespace or characters that follow an integer input, including the newline, will still be unread.  When you call `getline`, those characters will constitute the first line, so if you typed a number and pressed Enter, then the first line read will be empty.

Comment: Note that the above does not mean sprinkle "Just In Case" `cin.ignore()`s around your code. If you need to `ignore`, do it AFTER the the operation that left stuff in the stream that you need gone. If you preemptively place an `ignore` before a read, sooner or later you'll find a case where there's nothing you want ignored and instead you accidentally delete an input you did want.

Comment: @user4581301
@paddy
as you both said I tried using `cin.ignore()` before the `getline` it worked only for the first line but it deleted a letter from the second one so i used this code 
`     for (int i = 0; i < x; i++)
    {
        if(i == 0)
          cin.ignore();
        getline(cin, lines);
        File << endl << lines ;
    } ` , Thanks for help :D

Comment: You've misinterpreted what I wrote, done the opposite, and found exactly the bug I warned about. Find the input that doesn't read the newline you need removed, `cin >> x;`. Place the call to `ignore` AFTER that. By placing the `ignore()` pretty much anywhere else you have to complicate the code to prevent `ignore()`ing characters you do want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To store your strings you can use an [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) which is a variable size C++ container and is preferred to the C type arrays, here is an example with comments:

[**Live sample**](https://repl.it/@anastaciu/BothProfitableIntegers)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>

using namespace std; //for test purposes, in real code you shoud use std:: scope

int main()
{
    int x;
    string name, line;
    vector<string> lines; //container

    cout << "Input the file name to be opened : ";
    cin >> name;

    fstream File(name, ios::app | ios::out);

    cout << endl
         << "Input the number of lines to be written : ";
    cin >> x;
    cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n'); //needed because getline does not ignore new line characters
                                                         //explicitly looking to clear buffer till '\n', improves clarity
    cout << endl
         << "The lines are :";

    while (x > 0)
    {
        getline(cin, line);
        lines.push_back(line); //add lines to vector, this is assuming you need the lines in memory
        x--;                   //otherwise you could save them directly to the file
    }

    if (File.is_open())
    {
        for (string s : lines)  //writing all the lines to file
        {
            File << s << endl;
        }
        File.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: This answer has the `ignore()` in the correct place. See how much easier that is? Plus with the `ignore` in close proximity to `cin >> x;` the relationship is more apparent. The only thing I would do different is make it explicit that we're hunting for wascawy newlines and eat up any other debris with [`cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n')`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25020129/cin-ignorenumeric-limitsstreamsizemax-n)

Comment: @user4581301, yes, I reckon that it's an improvement.